# Passing a toolbox control to a method as parameter in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, controls, toolbox

I try to develop a dynamically created **toolbox control** in my website and I need to make that as efficient as possible.
I have two conditions like the following:

```
private void produceControls()
{
    if (General.survey_answer_type_id == 3)
        {
            rbtnList = new RadioButtonList();
            rbtnList.ID = "ControlID_3";
            SqlDataReader dr_answer = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr_answer.Read())
            {
                rbtnList.Items.Add(dr_answer["answer"].ToString());
            }

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(rbtnList);
        }
    else if (General.survey_answer_type_id == 4)
        {
            chkBoxList = new CheckBoxList();
            chkBoxList.ID = "ControlID_4";
            SqlDataReader dr_answer = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr_answer.Read())
            {
                chkBoxList.Items.Add(dr_answer["answer"].ToString());
            }
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(chkBoxList); 
        }
}
```

These conditions are the same except for the toolbox control name itself. I need to have a method to use in suitable conditions declared as (this is just an abstract):

```
public void foo(var toolbox_name)
{
        toolbox_name = new RadioButtonList();
        toolbox_name.ID = "ControlID_3";
        SqlDataReader dr_answer = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr_answer.Read())
        {
            toolbox_name.Items.Add(dr_answer["answer"].ToString());
        }
}
```

And then I want to use it like:

```
private void produceControls()
    {
        if (General.survey_answer_type_id == 3)
            {
                foo(rbtnList);
            }
        else if (General.survey_answer_type_id == 4)
            {
                foo(chkBoxList);
            }
    }
```

How could I achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: `public void foo(var toolbox_name)` are you familiar with passing a parameter as `Control`

Comment: are you familiar with `sender` and how to get the Controls name by Sender..? I think that you are making this harder than it should be also please show the full method signature in your first code example also this ` chkBoxList = new CheckBoxList();` is not visible outside the scope of the method so declare it at the class level perhaps a `public static chkBoxList = new CheckBoxList();`

Comment: change your method signature in this `private void produceControls()` to take a Control as a parameter I will look at this in a few I need to fix something on our production server

Comment: What is the query that you are expecting the datareader to execute..? you need to familiarize yourself with parameterized query's as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to know what the parent class of `CheckBoxlist` and `RadioButtonList` is. It is just `ListControl`.

For example:

```
public void showListControl(ListControl lstcontrol)
{
        lstcontrol.ID = "ControlID_3";
        SqlDataReader dr_answer = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr_answer.Read())
        {
            lstcontrol.Items.Add(dr_answer["answer"].ToString());
        }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
RadioButtonList rbtnList = new RadioButtonList();
showListControl(rbtnList);
```